# Refraction of Sound Waves

Tags: acoustics, refraction

When sound waves go from air to water what will happen to the wavelength and the angle of refraction?

I used the approach that we apply to light waves and concluded the wavelength will decrease and the wave will bend toward the normal since water is a denser, but the answer given in my book was the opposite. There was no explantion given, could you please explain.

Answer (score 2):

The speed of sound is greater in water than in air, so the wavelength in water is greater than in air. In effect the refractive index of the water is less than the refractive index of the air.

For light it is generally true that the refractive index is higher for denser materials, and this is because light interactions mainly with the electrons in a medium and a denser medium has more electrons per unit volume than a less dense medium. However sound is a pressure wave and its velocity in a medium is given by:

$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{K}{\rho}} $$

where $K$ is the [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus). The bulk modulus is basically how resistant the medium is to compression - high $K$ means hard to compress. Since water is (much) harder to compress than air it has a higher bulk modulus and therefore a higher speed of sound.

Answer (score 2):

Refraction occurs because of a change of speed of propagation of the wave.  When light passes from air to water it slows down, whereas when sound travels from air to water it speeds up.  Therefore sound is refracted away from the normal, whereas light is refracted towards the normal.